# How to prevent Showdown from removing script tags?

Tags: javascript, showdown

I was testing out something and tried to put this into Showdown:

```markdown
<script>alert("hacked!");</script>
```

Of course it didn't alert anything (Showdown is made to protect against those sorts of things), but the `<script>` tag gets removed completely.  I am using this for a user description, so the script tag (and it's contents) should be visible, just not executed.

I was thinking that most likely I would need to change some built in Showdown code but couldn't find any place in it's code that I should change to only **show** the script tags but **not execute** them.

Does anyone know any existing options or some changes to the source code to show this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer: I just needed to replace the start and end of the `<script>` tags with something visible, like `&lt;script` and `&lt;/script&gt;`

This is the code I used:

```
myshowdownhtml.split("<script").join("&lt;script").split("<"+"/script>").join("&lt;/script&gt;");
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this place in the code and it is responsible for hashing HTML tags such as: `<script>` or `</script>`.

https://github.com/showdownjs/showdown/blob/a9f38b6f057284460d6447371f3dc5dea999c0a6/src/subParsers/makehtml/hashHTMLBlocks.js

I think you should only delete lines 329 in the file

https://github.com/showdownjs/showdown/blob/a9f38b6f057284460d6447371f3dc5dea999c0a6/src/converter.js

And everything should work.

Comment: Hmmm, can not find that.  I am using Showdown v1.9.1

Comment: Find `text = showdown.subParser('hashHTMLBlocks')(text, options, globals);` on line 320 in file src/converter.js and delete him.

Comment: I tried but I can't find it.  I only have one file, showdown.min.js.  Downloaded from http://showdownjs.com

Comment: `showdown.min.js` is a file that is minified, i.e. contains the whole source code in one file. You have to use a non-miniffied version that contains the pure source code together with all directories.

Comment: Where can I find that code in the minified file?  I don't want the whole entire folder of source code and after removing one line have to minify it to one file again.